# Database: String Json vs new column

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm developing a website and I need to store some question.
I've a json like:

```
[{"id":"1","resp":"y"},{"id":"2","resp":"m"},{"id":"3","resp":"m"},{"id":"4","resp":"m"},{"id":"5","resp":"n"}
```

id = id question, 
resp = answer

I need to store this information and compare it with other user.
What's the best way? Store one single json for user o create a database like

```
        idquestion1 idquestion2 idquestion3 idquestion4
user        yes         no          yes         boh
```

Now I use Php+mysql

Comment: Relational databases store data in such a way so that the user (you) can extrapolate certain relation. Comparing one user to another user sounds like a relation to me. Therefore, by your definition there - the answer is obvious. Save data in a format that's usable by database and you.

Comment: Yeah I think is the best solution

Answer (score 1):

This would be the best table design imho:

```
user_id | question_id | answer
```